# grep regular expression to search a number sequence

Tags: regex, linux, windows, grep, cygwin

I have a large text file which I would like to grep-search. Structure of the file is like this:

```
8071656799 4661447177 0355654334 3019852932 8351070080 3427747396 : 3099000001
8711668395 3649821348 9956324354 5011010810 9136023566 9366447433 : 3099000002
5082147211 3084342012 9526906615 7367215108 0922482666 6485161555 : 3099000003
4029562459 5180764444 6007631229 0296033611 6410243961 1599676529 : 3099000004
2029562935 7403306551 4667331755 4708680737 0948271458 0585681992 : 3099000005
3980586858 2774838233 2196908474 1817405080 5501649035 3043116116 : 3099000006
4821697167 9339115830 6953440258 6707173876 7188037671 5127476767 : 3099000007
0341392607 4082292483 7807211229 1753819242 4269141779 6567687980 : 3099000008
```

I would like to find certain sequence of numbers while ignoring spaces, colons, ends of lines and last 10 digits of each line.  For example 8034277473968711 wil be found on the  first two rows:

**80 3427747396** : 3099000001 **8711**

Please, can you help me with the grep regular expression for such task? Or any other way to resolve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You can match the same sequence in other ways within first two rows.

Comment: I don't believe it would be practical in regex - what is your favourite programming language? :)

Comment: Are you just looking for the number of occurrences of a given sequence?  Or do you need to know where they're at in the file?  I'm wondering if we can't remove all the unwanted characters (the whitespace and the last 10 digits of each line) and then search for the number of occurrences that way.

Comment: Linux or Windows? Or windows into a Linux program? Or Linux running under Windows?

Comment: @Lev Levitsky : How?

Comment: @Aprillion : Well, I am not programmer at all :-) I like R though...

Comment: @thataustin : Just the number of occurences

Comment: @Jongware : Windows - cygwin

Comment: **80**71656799 4661447177 0**3**5565**4**334 301985**2**932 83510**7**0080 342**7**7**47**39**6** : 3099000001
**8711**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`sed -e 's/\s//g' < sed -e 's/:[0-9]\+$//g' < inputFileName | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | grep -o "8034277473968711"`

I tested this in an AWS Ubuntu 14.04 microInstance.

We're running and piping it through  series of `sed`s here and closing it off with a grep -o.  The -o flag prevents a huge wall of text with arbitrary highlighting since you're dealing with a large data set.  It should now show only the result, while eliminating all the stuff you didn't want in it's computation.

Replace **inputFileName** with your file name and the numbers in parentheses with whatever you'd like to search for (no spaces, just straight numbers).

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, under cygwin, your solution produces "-bash: sed: No such file or directory" error. I tried to change single quotes to double quotes but failed. Anybody familiar with cygwin?

Comment: Hi Mira.  Try using the full path in double quotes - IE "C:\Users\My User\My File.format".  To be really honest, I would use a Linux VirtualBox (or AWS MicroInstance) just to get used to the Linux environment.  Learning on Cygwin is tough because the filesystem is interpreted differently -often leading to things such as path complications.

Comment: by that windows path, did you mean `/cygdrive/c/Users/My\ User/My\ File.format`?

Comment: Indeed I did.  Thanks!

Comment: Also - it's been some years since I used Cygwin so please do correct me if I'm wrong - but I thought you could encapsulate the path in parentheses and avoid having to use the escaped sequence `\ `to signify a space in path name, IE using `"/cygdrive/c/Users/My User/My File.format"`

Answer (score -1):

Step 1:
use this pattern to capture all possible number sequences

```
(?=((?:\d(?:\s:\s\d+\r?\n|\s)?){16}))\d
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/144)

---

Step 2:
Loop through previous matches and perform a replace using this pattern

```
\s:\s\d+\r?\n|\s
```

and replace with nothing

---

Step 3:
compare step #2 results to your desired sequence `8034277473968711`
match found at the 49th match.

Comment: why do you need step 1?

Comment: @Aprillion, to find and capture all possible number sequences.

Comment: repeating yourself will not make your reasons any clearer - what is stopping you to apply step 2 directly on the source data? what is supposed to be beneficial about the seven headed dragon of arbitrary capture groups you call step 1? did you choose 16 because the example in OP happens to have 16 digits?

Comment: I smell sarcasm but that's ok. I interpreted this statement `I would like to find certain sequence of numbers` as 16 digits in a row that could be anywhere in the source data and interrupted by a white space `\s` and/or `\s:\s\d+`, I am generating all possible scenarios (step #1) to find the match's position in the intact source data as step #2 alone will alter it. I hope it makes sense now.